# Compare two files via comp command in vb

Tags: batch-file, command

I have tried to compare two file via "comp file1 file2" batch command. it works fine. however it will asked "Compare more files (Y/N) ? " I know how to solve by using

echo n| comp file1 file2

however when I including this  command on .bat file or in VB , the command is not going to work, it seems to have loop problem. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it ?

I tried FC command, but i don't think it work really well. as comp will stop if it found 10 differences between two files, and FC will needs to run it till end. which will spend a lot of time for big files.

Comment: Are you testing binary or text files?

Comment: I am testing with binary files

Comment: @magoo You will have to use the `/b` switch with `FC` in that case, and it will not stop after 10 miscompares but has to compare the entire files (unless the filesizes are different of course).

Comment: yes, it i add /b switch, it will took long time to compare for the files, therefore i prefer to use "comp" command as it will stop after 10 miscompares.however I can not stop it asking "Compare more files" unless use echo n|comp file1 file2. which is not working in bat file or in VB

Comment: When using `comp` The piped `n` character works fine in a batch file - I haven't tried VB but if the command line is right then it should work there too.  How does it fail?

Comment: when I put echo n|comp file1 file2 in comp.bat (just one single command) if will not stop.. will loop.. could you provid me the batch file so i can have a try

Comment: You called your batch file `comp` so name it something else.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, once I change the batch file name to comp. it is working now. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fc file1 file2 >nul
```

will set `errorlevel` to 0 if the files are the same, non-zero otherwise.

can be tested with

```
fc "file2" "file2" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo Files are different) else (echo files are the same)
```

`"quotes are required"` around filenames if they contain spaces.